# Screenshot by chrome extenstion get huge memory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've try to make a screenshot from current page when tab is switched. Based on the google documents I wrote this code:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo){
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function(screenshotUrl) {
        if( typeof(screenshotUrl) != 'undefined' ){
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: screenshotUrl
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When this extension is activated and I change the tab in first time, chrome get memory frequently while free memory is finished and windows close the chrome automatically!
Where is my problem?! Is this a chrome bug?!

***note: I test the code with different conditions. Just when extension want to download the screen shot there is this problem. Another codes after screenshot have not any problem***

Comment: Yep, sounds like a bug. Try freeing the memory via [URL.revokeObjectURL(screenshotUrl)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL).